When to save a collaborative editing application to the database
I am trying to create a collaborative editing application like Google Spread Sheet. How should I know when to save the data to the database? For example, if we are collaborating on a single article, should we update the database each time a change is made, such as writing or deleting text?
Let's say our tech stack is React + y.js + blocknote(editor) for the front end and the database is stored in supabase.
I would like to know the appropriate timing for updates to the database.
